# Include jar file when creating an R package

Tags: java, r, rjava

I created a skeleton R package:

```
lib
 jarFileHere.jar 
R
 r_code_file.R
```

The *r_code_file.R* tries to references a class file in *jarFileHere.jar*:

```
library("rJava")
library("rjson")

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  .jpackage(pkgname, lib.loc=libname)
}

.onLoad("packagename", "../lib/jarFileHere.jar")

.jnew("com/test/ClassHere", "")
```

But I get a failure due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I was able to get it to work using

```
.jinit
.jaddClassPath("../lib/jarFileHere.jar")
```

but the rJava docs explicitly says not to use .jinit because it won't work when the code is used as a package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your structure like:

```
inst
 java
  jarFileHere.jar 
R
 r_code_file.R
```

For examples on how to include java in your package look at the [helloJavaWorld](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/helloJavaWorld/index.html) package.

Also take a look at the source of [Deducer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Deducer/index.html) and [DeducerplugInExample](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DeducerPlugInExample/index.html). There is a tutorial on including java code in your package available on Deducer's web manual: 
http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#suaptijc