# Import a Java (jar) written file in R

Tags: java, r, jar, statistics

I want to run a jar file in r console.

Is this possible in R?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843816/how-to-include-jar-file-when-creating-a-r-package you can refer this

Comment: I'm not writing an R package. I'm trying to import a jar file in R.

Comment: Perhaps it would help others help you if you were clearer about what you are trying to do, especially since the first two comments made (a valid, given the vagueness) assumption that this was package-related. If you just want to "run" a JAR file as you would from a cmd or terminal shell, then Nikita's answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work

```
x <- system("java -jar /path/to/my.jar")
```

Parameters of the system function: [System](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html)